# Django displaying 2 tables side by side

Tags: html, css, django, templates

As the title says, i'm trying to display 2 tables side by side. I tried a couple of methods but no one shows results.

Right now this is the code of the 2 tables:

```
<div>
   <table style="float: left" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
       {% for item in product %}
           {% if item.orden_ref_id == orden.id %}
               <tr>
                   <td>
                      {{ item.articulo }}
                   </td>
               </tr>
           {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
   </table>
   <table style="float: right" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
       {% for item in valor %}
           {% if item.refer_id == orden.id %}
               {% if item.show_ref == '2' %}
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           {{ item.costo }}
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               {% endif %}
           {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
   </table>
</div>
```

but it look like this:

[Tables look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD0yh.png)

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the div's around the table.  If are using bootstrap you make a surrounding row and then make each table a column.  If not using bootstrap then see this page for adding the necessary CSS, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp

```
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col">
   <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
       {% for item in product %}
           {% if item.orden_ref_id == orden.id %}
               <tr>
                   <td>
                      {{ item.articulo }}
                   </td>
               </tr>
           {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
   </table>
</div>
<div class = "col">
   <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
       {% for item in valor %}
           {% if item.refer_id == orden.id %}
               {% if item.show_ref == '2' %}
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           {{ item.costo }}
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               {% endif %}
           {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
   </table>
<div class = "col">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you mark it as the answer? I'm desperate for stack overflow points here @Aidenweiss